# How to set value to vars.tfvars or variables.tf in terraform from Jenkins string parameter

Tags: terraform, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, infrastructure-as-code

Is there way to set a value for `vars.tfvars` by passing a string parameter from Jenkins?

Jenkins sting parameter. This is groovy scripeted pipeline

[image]

```
cat vars.tfvars
```

[image]

```
cat variables.tf
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic values should be passed through the command line. And you can make use of `.tfvars` file and command-line arguments at the same time like

`terraform apply -var-file=vars.tfvars -var domain_name=test`

and command line value will always take precedence over the value given in `.tfvars` file

so in the case of groovy, it can go like

`sh 'terraform apply -var-file=vars.tfvars -var domain_name=${domain_name}'`

Comment: any other way to inject the value into `.tfvars` file?